# How to build notepad++ source code using Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, notepad++

Picked notepad++ source to learn some best practices and sneak inside code of this popular text editor.

The readme file says -

> Double click on
>   Notepad++\trunk\PowerEditor\visual.net\notepadPlus.vcproj to launch
>   Notepad++ project in Visual Studio, then build it with the mode you
>   want, that's it.

But attempting to build this in VS-2012 RC build fails with errors saying - 1. some files missing, 2. IntelliSense: pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed.

To keep the question concise and readable, not posting exact error. Please let me know if it is required.

**EDIT**
Added Errors, as per request -

> Error 1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'FindCharsInRange.h':
>   No such file or
>   directory c:\myLocalSourcePath\notepad++\powereditor\src\Notepad_plus.h   68  1   Notepad++
>
> Error 8   error C2511: 'void ScintillaEditView::getGenericText(TCHAR
>   *,int,int,int *,int *) const' : overloaded member function not found in
>   'ScintillaEditView'   c:\myLocalSourcePath\Notepad++\PowerEditor\src\ScitillaComponent\ScintillaEditView.cpp  1715    1   Notepad++
>
> 16  IntelliSense: cannot open source file
>   "VerticalFileSwitcher.h"  c:\myLocalSourcePath\Notepad++\PowerEditor\src\NppCommands.cpp  35  1   Notepad++
>
> 17  IntelliSense: cannot open source file
>   "documentMap.h"   \Notepad++\PowerEditor\src\NppCommands.cpp  36  1   Notepad++
>
> 25  IntelliSense: identifier "FindCharsInRangeDlg" is
>   undefined c:\myLocalSourcePath\Notepad++\PowerEditor\src\Notepad_plus.h   351 2   Notepad++

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: You're missing at least one include directory, the error is pretty clear.  Figure out where these header files are and add the directory to your include path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could fix the issue, after changing the build profile. Posting here in hope it could be helpful to someone, one day.

1. Previously it was selected as ANSI Debug Build. It had to be changed
   to Unicode Debug build.
2. I had to delete Notepad++.exe Manifest file.

At this point of time build succeeded.

However while running the application, Scintilla DLL could not be located, as a hack I copied SCiLexer.DLL from installed Notepad++ directory in, Program Files to bin directory inside Notepad++ source code.

Comment: Worked for me, except I did not have to change the build type or delete the manifest file. I did have to get the SCiLexer.DLL like you said.

Comment: *** Notepad++ COMES WITH a manifest file: Visual Studio automatically attempts to generate one when you build. Simply open up Project Properties -> Linker -> Manifest File, and turn off "Generate Manifest"***. Also, as for SCiLexer.DLL... if you had read the readme that comes with Notepad++ source code, you must first build the Scintilla source code (using Visual Studio's developer command prompt and nmake), and then copy the DLL file over to the PowerEditor Bin directory. Just read the readme in the root of the source code archive.